# How do I complete the "A Brilliant Smile" triumph?

Tags: destiny-2

One of the Triumphs for this year's Festival of the Lost, apparently requires my Guardian to brush my teeth. This doesn't really seem to be very descriptive, but is a required triumph to obtain the Eris Morn mask.

[image]

Now I've tried some things -- I've tried talking to tower vendors for toothbrushes they might sell, but I've come up short. I've tried brushing my own teeth in real life, but Bungie hasn't notified me of completion there, so that's a no.

In any case, how do I brush my teeth to get A Brilliant Smile?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To brush your teeth, you'll need a toothbrush. In order to get a toothbrush, you'll need to finish a quest chain that only starts after you've completed Eva's quests and obtained a Festival of the Lost mask.

1. Speak to Eva in the **Tower** and complete her quests

   - Complete a run of the Haunted Forest
   - Obtain one of the Festival of the Lost Masks (has icon of Master Rahool)
2. Speak to Eris Morn, located at the **Moon**

   - In order to start the quest chain, you need to have your Mask equipped.
   - You should receive the quest item, Box of Raisins
3. Speak to Spider, located at the **Tangled Shore**

   - Complete the quest Even Handed, which requires 12 Fallen, Scorn, Hive and Cabal enemy kills on the Tangled Shore
   - You should receive the quest item, Winged Chew
4. Speak to Anastasia Bray, located on on **Mars**

   - Complete the quest Armed to the Teeth, which requires 10 Kinetic, Energy, and Power weapon kills on enemies in Mars
   - You should receive the quest item, Unchocolate
5. Speak to Asher Mir, located on **Io**

   - Complete the quest Precisely, which requires 10 precision final blows on both Vex and Taken on Io
   - You should receive the quest item, Piece of Celery
6. Speak to Brother Vance, located on **Mercury**

   - Complete the quest In Your Element, which requires 10 Arc, Solar, and Void kills in Mercury
   - You should receive the quest item, Splice Drops
7. Speak to Failsafe, located on **Nessus**

   - Complete the quest Touched by the Light, which requires 5 Fallen, Vex, and Cabal kills on Nessus using abilities.
   - You should receive the quest item, Salted Sweets
8. Speak to Devrim Kay, located at the **EDZ**

   - Complete the quest Foregone Conclusions, which requires 5 Fallen, Cabal, and Taken finishers in the EDZ
   - You should receive the quest item, Sour Engram
9. Speak to Petra Venj, located in the **Dreaming City**

   - Complete the quest The Best of My Abilities, which requires 5 melee and grenade ability kills, and 10 super kills in the Dreaming City
   - You should receive the quest item, Sugary Engram
10. Speak to Sloane, located on **Titan**

    - Complete the quest Not In Our House, which requires an undisclosed amount of kills in the Solarium, Festering Halls, and Arboretum in Titan
    - Each kill seems to reward 3.5% progress in the Solarium, and 7% in the Festering Halls and Arboretum
    - You should receive the quest item, Void Fizz
11. Return back to the **Moon** and speak to Eris Morn

    - Complete the quest The Dance of My People, by dancing for Eris.
    - You should receive a Goody Bag, and a Toothbrush.

Open your inventory, and use the Toothbrush located in the Consumables section, and you will have finally been granted the ability to brush your Guardian's teeth! If you've finished all the quest steps correctly, you will now have a Used Toothbrush sitting in your inventory.

[image]

Comment: This is *way* too many steps for a simple task.

Comment: @Draco18s It's the festival of the lost! The reward wasn't worth the several hours I spent doing it though.

Comment: @Draco18s Dental hygiene is critically important if you want to live a long life as a Guardian :)

Answer (score 11):

There is quest chain to receive toothbrush:

> The triumph for the FotL 2019 to brush your teeth can be completed by flooding a quest began by visiting Eris on the moon. She will give you an item, which will have a description leading you to a planetary vendor. The first one is The Spider. From there, you will get an easy objective to complete, followed by another item. Follow this chain throughout the solar system and you’ll get a toothbrush.

Quest item should be consumable item:

> Look in consumables and look for a common rarity consumable with a festival of the lost icon

Also  looks like there are some prerequisites:

> In order to participate in this activity, all new light players will have to:
>
> - Achieve Power Level 770 or more
> - Complete Escape The Comsodrome Quest to unlock the tower.

Sources: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/doupu2/a_brilliant_smile_brush_your_teeth_festival_of/), [Festival Of Lost all loot guide](https://errorfixer.co/destiny-2-festival-of-the-lost-all-loot-guide/)

Comment: I've tried speaking to Eris Morn, she only gives me the daily/weekly bounties and the campaign mission offering. Didn't receive anything.

Comment: added prerequisites